# NullPointerException while calling setText method in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I tried to set text in TextView in fragment from main class but got NullPointerException. I've initialized TextView in onCreateView(...) but it did not help.

Here is my fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                                   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                                   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <TextView
            android:text="@string/back_card"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="217dp"
            android:layout_height="290dp"
            android:id="@+id/cardBack"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="221dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="97dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="221dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="97dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/spy_font"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".PlayersCards"
        android:background="@color/white">

    <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="317dp"
            android:layout_height="465dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/container">

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is activity code:

```
public class PlayersCards extends AppCompatActivity {

    private boolean showingBack;
    public static List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    FrameLayout card;

    CardBackFragment cardBackFragment = new CardBackFragment();
    CardFrontFragment cardFrontFragment = new CardFrontFragment();

    TextView playerLabel;

    public static class CardFrontFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView roleLabel, wordLabel;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view;
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_front, container, false);

            roleLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.roleTextView);
            wordLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);

            return view;
        }

        public CardFrontFragment setRoleLabel(String text) {
            roleLabel.setText(text);

            return this;
        }

        public CardFrontFragment setWordLabel(String text) {
            wordLabel.setText(text);

            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class CardBackFragment extends Fragment {

        TextView playerLabel;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view;
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card_back, container, false);
            playerLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardBack);
            return view;
        }

        public CardBackFragment setPlayerLabel(String text) {
            playerLabel.setText(text);

            return this;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_players_cards);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, cardBackFragment)
                    .commit();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.finalCountOfSpies; i++) {
            roles.add(Role.SPY);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < MainActivity.finalCountOfPlayers - MainActivity.finalCountOfSpies; i++) {
            roles.add(Role.PLAYER);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(roles);

        card = findViewById(R.id.container);
        playerLabel = card.findViewById(R.id.cardBack);
        playerLabel.setText("TEXTTEXTTEXT");

        card.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flipCard();
            }
        });
    }

    private void flipCard() {
        if (showingBack) {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(
                            R.anim.card_flip_right_in,
                            R.anim.card_flip_right_out,
                            R.anim.card_flip_left_in,
                            R.anim.card_flip_left_out
                    )
                    .replace(R.id.container, cardBackFragment.setPlayerLabel("BLABLABLA"))
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

            showingBack = false;
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(
                            R.anim.card_flip_left_in,
                            R.anim.card_flip_left_out,
                            R.anim.card_flip_right_in,
                            R.anim.card_flip_right_out
                    )
                    .replace(R.id.container, cardFrontFragment.setRoleLabel("ROLELABEL").setWordLabel("WORDWORDWORD"))
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

            showingBack = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dadry.spygame/com.name.spygame.PlayersCards}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                        at com.dadry.spygame.PlayersCards.onCreate(PlayersCards.java:102)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
```

I tried initialize TextView in fragment class. I also tried to create fragments objects as activity class' attributes. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing is that your 'architecture' is terrible. Why you're using static classes for you fragments? Why not create separate classes for fragments outside of activity and separate them? It's look awful and wrong in all dimensions of android development.
The second thing is that playerLabel will be null, because you can't add fragment to layout and then find the view inside that fragment using the id of container. If you're using that approach with static fragments(which is crazy), then to set the text to textView you should you that setter from CardBackFragment. Just call cardBackFragment. setPlayerLabel(). It should work.